# Querying DynamoDb GSI In parallel using Java Lambda expression Parallel Stream

Tags: java, list, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, collectors

I would like to query DynamoDB GSI in bulk but there are no batch operations available for DynamoDB. Instead, I am try to parallelize the query by parallel streaming the list of value and calling the DynamoDBMapper query API.

The expectation is, I would use Java Lambda expression to stream a Collection(List in my case)  in parallel and then query the DynamoDB which expected to return list of list of objects, I would flatten them to get a single list.

I have code like below:
Sample code:

```
List<String> customerName = {1000+ records};

List<Customer> customerList = customerName.parallelStream()
           .map((custName) -> {

                /* Few other operations to build the QueryExpression 
                   expressing using custName
                */

               // this returns PaginatedQueryList<Customer>
               return  DynamoDBMapper.query(Customer.class, QueryExpression);

           }).flatMap(list -> list.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In the above code, I expect to have `List<Customer>` as an output but it does not seem to be working.

Step by Step actual outputs:

1. `DynamoDBMapper.query` - returns `PaginatedQueryList<Customer>`
2. `.map` - returns `Stream<PaginatedQueryList>`
3. `.flatMap` - returns `Stream<Object>`
4. `.collect` - returns `Object`

However, I would expect `.flatMap` to return `Stream<Customer>` and `.collect` to return a `List<Customer>`

Can you please help me identify what I am missing here? Thank you.

Comment: Does merging it all to one line `.flatMap( custName -> {
               // this returns PaginatedQueryList<Customer>
               List<Customer> queryRes =   DynamoDBMapper.query(Customer.class, QueryExpression);
return queryRes.stream();})` work for you?

Comment: What  I meant focusing on was this `List<Customer> queryRes = DynamoDBMapper.query(Customer.class, QueryExpression);` is this cast appropriate? If so, I don't see a reason for the `flatMap` to not work or return `Stream<Object>`.

Comment: @Naman Thank you! I did not cast correctly and it worked once I fixed it.